# Как выровнять горизонтальный RecyclerView снизу?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как выровнять горизонтальный RecyclerView по низу?
Например, у меня есть горизонтальный RecyclerView с LinearLayoutManager-ом, который выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При этом я хотела бы, чтобы все элементы RecyclerView были выровнены по нижней линии, так, например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть ли какой-нибудь способ это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте для каждого item-а в разметке контейнер  вроде такого:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Суть в том, что сам контейнер должен иметь размер самой большой View из вашего списка, а внутри него будет сама View которая просто будет привязана к низу этого контейнера и скейлится снизу вверх.